# Who actually knows Saitama is as strong as he is?

Tags: one-punch-man

Other than Genos, King, and those he's defeated(if they even knew they were fighting him), who else knows his secret? It seemed to me the Hero Assoc. still hasn't taken a real notice.

Answer (score 3):

Going by the chapter 102 of the Shonen Jump Manga:

> Genos, King, Silver Fang, Blizzard, and (possibly) Mumen Rider

Comment: Welcome to the Animanga SE. Could you possibly specify which chapter this is, as the “current chapter” will change over time?

Comment: Hi, can you explain how Blizzard know Saitama true strength?

Comment: @IamaStudent Presumably this is referring to how Blizzard attempts to newbie-crush him with utter futility, is protected by Saitama from a blast from Genos, and then watches said S-class Demon Cyborg be subservient and obedient to Saitama, while Saitama curb stomps the apparent villain Demon Cyborg was having trouble with and that she was thinking might be a Dragon Class threat. And later she finds out that King, Bang, and Bomb are all basically bros with Saitama.  So she knows he's stronger than her, and knows he's strong enough to earn the respect of the strongest, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Suiryu seems to recognize Saitama's incredible power when they first meet, but only after their bout does he realize that his strength is nothing compared to baldy's.
Also, down the road (Monster Association arc and onward spoilers):

> After the huge battle with MA and Garou, some heroes see that Saitama is actually really OP. Some of these are Sweet Mask, Zombie Man and even Tatsumaki begins to suspect something after the battle.
>  Also, in the latest webcomic chapters, Flashy Flash sees that Saitama is strong, but instead of respecting him he tells him that he wishes to train him in order to make him even better, not knowing that Saitama's overwhelming speed and strength really *don't need* any more perfecting.

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you could [edit] and state the specific webcomic chapters instead of "latest webcomic chapters" because they will change over the time, and finding the chapters based on date is usually not easy. Thanks!